# What is the python 'requests' api equivalent to my shell scripts curl command?

Tags: python, bash, curl, python-requests

I have this curl command I use a shell script:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--cert /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/${PEFQDN}.pem \
--key /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/${PEFQDN}.pem \
--cacert /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem \
--data "{ \"name\": \"$GROUP\", \"parent\": \"00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000\", \"environment\": \"production\", \"classes\": { \"$CLASS\": {}} }" \
https://${PEFQDN}:4433/classifier-api/v1/groups | python -m json.tool
```

I want to get away from my shell script as I need to be able to process some complex json that comes back from the REST API. I figure I'd use `python` and the `requests` package.  I was looking at this documentation:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

But I do not see where I can specify my certificate info. In my shell script I can pass `curl` these options: `--cert`, `--key`, `--cacert`. I do not know how to accomplish the same with python's `requests` API.  Does anyone out know how I can accomplish this?

UPDATE:  Thanks Joran.  Here is my attempt to write a python script to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests

# curl https://${PEFQDN}:4433/classifier-api/v1/groups \
# -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
# --cert /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/${PEFQDN}.pem \
# --key /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/${PEFQDN}.pem \
# --cacert /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem | python -m json.tool

url='https://my-pm.example.com:4433/classifier-api/v1/groups'
headers = {"Content-Type: application/json"}
data={}
cacert='/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem'
key='/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/my-pm.example.com.pem'
cert='/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/my-pm.example.com.pem'
result = requests.get(url,
        data=data, #whatever data
        headers=headers, #dict {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
        verify=cert,
        cert=(cacert,key) #key/cert pair 
        )
print result.json()
```

And I must be doing something wrong because this is the output I get ...

```
# ./add-group.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./add-group.py", line 21, in <module>
    cert=(cacert,key) #key/cert pair 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 451, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 382, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/models.py", line 293, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg/requests/models.py", line 401, in prepare_headers
    self.headers = CaseInsensitiveDict((to_native_string(name), value) for name, value in headers.items())
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
headers = {"Content-Type: application/json"}
```

should be changed to

```
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

Looks like the requests API is expecting a dictionary, and {"Content-Type: application/json"} is apparently a Python set.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = requests.get(url,
        data=data, #whatever data
        headers=headers, #dict {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
        cert=(cacert,key),#key/cert pair 
        verify="cert_chain.pem" 
        )
print result.json() #depending on version of requests, json may be a function or a property
```

this link will be helpful

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: Maybe this is obvious enough that it doesn't need to be pointed out, but it should be `post()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: it should work identically regardless of post/get/push

Comment: Thanks Joran, but I still don't get what I am doing wrong in my python script.  I have updated my question with my attempt to write this in python. Please take a look. Thank you

Comment: `headers = {"Content-Type: application/json"}` is not the same as `headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}` one is a dictionary with one key/value pair, the other is a set with a single string element ...